# Not able to ping to the virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

To start: I am a novice in using VirtualBox.
Two physical machines: 
**1]** Windows machine (local): Created VM (vbox + vdi files). Set "Host-only" networking. Set IP static: 192.168.56.101.
**2]** Linux machine (remote:only have ssh access): Created a VM with the same configuration. Copied the image file (.vdi file) from windows to that machine.
Then I am starting the VM in the remote machine using the headless option and trying to ping to that VM, but it is always showing: [P.S: In windows, I am able to ping/ssh (using putty) to the local VM]

```
PING 192.168.56.101 (192.168.56.101) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.56.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.56.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.56.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

The virtual machine settings file (~/.VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml) contains this line:

```
DHCPServer networkName="vboxnet0" IPAddress="192.168.56.1" networkMask="255.255.255.0" lowerIP="192.168.56.101" upperIP="192.168.56.254" enabled="1"
```

And the ifconfig contains (rest stripped):

```
vboxnet0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0A:00:27:00:00:00
      inet addr:192.168.56.1  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::800:27ff:fe00:0/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:151 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:21552 (21.0 KiB)
```

Can anyone tell me what I am missing here..!!!
Output of *VBoxManage showvminfo* is

```
NIC 1:           MAC: 0800275829C9, Attachment: Host-only Interface 'vboxnet0', Cable connected: on, Trace: off (file: none), Type: 82540EM, Reported speed: 0 Mbps, Boot priority: 0, Promisc Policy: deny, Bandwidth group: none
```

Comment: You might do better asking this on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com)

Comment: What are you expecting will carry the packets from one VM to the other?

Comment: no sir, i wanted the host (the remote machine) to be able to ping to a VM (on the same remote host)

Answer (score 1):

So you have two VM's on different host systems, where both VM's network settings are set to "Host only" and want to establish a connection between them? It won't work. You have to give the VMs access to your network, in your case preferrably by using the bridged network setting (and proper routing, of course).